# CSS Dropping For Certain Controls

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik, rad-controls

We have a pretty complex application design with a bunch of telerik controls.  Every now and then, we get issues where the associated CSS to a file are lost, and the controls are not styled.  So for instance, after an async postback (a couple of postbacks into the life of the page), the CSS for the textbox, date picker, combo, and other controls are lost.  It's not complete; some controls still appear as they normally do, I don't think it's all inclusive.

Any idea why and how I can debug, and determine why they get lost?  Anything I can do to work around it?

Thanks.

Brian

Comment: Incidentally, I've seen this happen once in awhile for major websites, like SO itself and forums.asp.net.  Sometimes I just see the text content in paragraphs flowing from left margin to right margin without any surrounding content.  I refresh the page and it goes away.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that a web site can drop certain requests due to a brief network failure... for us, the problem doesn't go away across postbacks, only until you come back into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadStyleSheetManager can help, but statically defining the CSS is the solution to this weird problem.  RadStylesheetManager also gets references to the control dynamically and would have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [RadStyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html)?

Comment: No, I think I'll try that.  I don't know if that's the answer to this specific problem as the problem is that the CSS reference is lost...